# Discussion about JavaScript snippet compilation

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

`let` and `const` do not allow duplicate declaration.

Currently this below snippet throwsone (first) error for `let`. But I am expecting it should be throwing two (for `let` and `const`) errors instead of only the first (one) error.

```js
const yy=1;
const yy=2;
console.log(yy+yy);//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'yy' has already been declared",

let zz=1;
let zz=2;
console.log(zz+zz);//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'zz' has already been declared",
```

When you run the snippet, it says

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'yy' has already been declared",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 7
}
```

But I can see two errors in Chrome browser, output is

[image]

I guess the snippet compilation stops, if any one error has occurred. But it would be nice if snippets compile the full code and throw all errors instead of only the first error. Like

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'yy' has already been declared",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 7
},
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'zz' has already been declared",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 7
}
```

Because if the user knows all errors, then it helps to fix all those errors quickly instead of running the snippets for every bug fix.

Comment: ... this has nothing to do with stack snippets.. You cannot change the reference when you declare as `const`

Comment: @SurajRao const and let also doing the same for variable deceleration. i know that.   have you read my question fully? my question is why the snippet throwing one error instead of two error.

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior of javascript in browsers? I mean, if I execute this code outside a stack-snipped, I also only get the first error. If I start it in a different browser, then I get completely different error messages. So how do you expect what you want to happen? (Unless you want SO to write their own javascript engine that does what you want).

Comment: I have edited my question for more understand to you guys.

Comment: alright.. my bad. apologies. but I have to agree with the answer here... Browsers interpret JS and show the 1st error.. unless you use a separate JS engine

Comment: @RameshRajendran when executing the complete code in browser console, I've only got the first error. If I only keep the second part, I've indeed got "SyntaxError: redeclaration of let zz". The snippet seems to react correctly IMO.

Comment: And again, stop tagging questions with `[discussion]` ___and___ `[feature-request]`. ___Especially___ if your question is actually a bug report. And again, if you're submitting a bug report, ___test it first___.

Answer (score 9):

> I guess the snippet compilation stopped

This is not an issue with Stack Snippets. That is the way the language is designed. If there is an error, all execution stops.

Running this code in any other environment will produce the same error you encountered, and stop execution at the same place as well.

Any user attempting to use this type of code setup in their own environment will be presented with the same exact error the snippet produces here.

For example, this is what it looks like in my chrome browser:
[image: chrome example]

Here is what happens in a jsfiddle:
[image: jsfiddle example]

Here is the same jsfiddle run from edge (note still only one error, although let's face it, Edge is just painful):
[image: Edge jsfiddle example]

Comment: Nope. When i debug my JavaScript code locally. I can see more than one error in my console window.

Comment: How do you test it locally. Tell us exactly what you do, which browser you use, which steps you take to get more error messages. I tested with Chrome and Edge and in both cases only the first error appears.

Comment: @BDL In my development environment. I can see multiple errors in console window. the compilation does not exist if an any error is occurred.

Comment: @Travis . I am unable to see any images.

Comment: You must have imgur blocked.

Comment: @TravisJ Now I can see. Did you see my question?

Comment: @RameshRajendran maybe you should clarify which development environment you use

Comment: @rene I have tried this Angular 2 project  in Visual studio 2015

Comment: To me it would seem that the only way you got different errors as shown in your question would be to have generated one, edited the code, ran the script, and generated the second one.

Comment: @RameshRajendran typescript is _transpiled_ to javascript in such a setup and shows all errors..It is not interpreted..

Comment: @SurajRao Are you sure? because it is compiled as JavaScript code. Then only I can see these errors.  So it is a JavaScript code only

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes.. javascript unlike typescript is _interpreted_ by the browser..It may be the same code but typescript compiler works differently

Comment: Okay. let me leave this. I suggest it would be nice if the User can see all errors instead run the snippet every time to fix all errors.

Comment: @RameshRajendran try the typescript online playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20yy%3D1%3B%0D%0Aconst%20yy%3D2%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(yy%2Byy)%3B%2F%2FUncaught%20SyntaxError%3A%20Identifier%20'yy'%20has%20already%20been%20declared%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20zz%3D1%3B%0D%0Alet%20zz%3D2%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(zz%2Bzz)%3B%2F

Comment: I can't see any errors there @SurajRao . It  allow to run

Comment: It is changing the let/const declarations into var there, so no errors show in the execution. Not sure that is the best example to use.

Comment: really? no squiggly lines and hovering over it doesnt show the message?

Comment: From that angle, yeah there are the red squiggly lines, and hovering them shows the message. However, that is somewhat different.

Comment: yeah.. my point was typescript transpiles the code to javascript and can show the set of errors while your fiddle and browser interprets plain javascript. Stack-snippet doesnt look like it was meant to act like typescript..